# Avoid 'waiting for response' in php?

Tags: php, curl, response

I have a php script that uses exec() function to execute curl to download file. The file is about 600mb. So when I acess the php file on a browser, browsers shows me 'waiting for response' message.

How do I avoid that?

my php source is

$a = exec("curl 'http://lab.test.com/test/test/down.php?c=23212' -o 'test.avi'");

Comment: I believe there's a way to call `exec` to run asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a Linux host, you should only need to add `&` to the end of your `exec()` call:

```
$a = exec("curl 'http://lab.test.com/test/test/down.php?c=23212' -o 'test.avi' &");
```

It's a little more complex for Windows:

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$a = $WshShell->Run("curl 'http://lab.test.com/test/test/down.php?c=23212' -o 'test.avi'", 0, false);
```

Comment: this can be not work on windows platform, can be not work in non-bash console installed by default.